# Remove and move elements in a WebBrowser Control page

Tags: c#, html

I'm making some changes to a page on a WebBrowser Control. There is some indications in the code. I just want to make sure that I don't have any unnecessary lines of code.

```
namespace AL4
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {       
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("gpu_notice").Style = "display:none"; // hide gpu_notice element
            webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("header").OuterHtml = ""; // delete header element
            webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ads").OuterHtml = ""; // delete ads element
            webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("the_game").Style += "position: absolute; top: 0px; right: 0px;"; // align the_game element to the center of the webbrowser
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Your code looks fine, if a bit short for review. I also don't understand what you mean with "indications in the code". Hope you still get good reviews!

Comment: Thanks. By "indications in the code", I meant to indicate those // delete... (for example).

Answer (score 1):

I think all your 4 lines of code are very necessary in your application, but you forgot for example about error handling. If one of your four IDs disappear you'll get a juicy exception.

Comment: But can I do it better?